# write関数の第三引数にINT_MAX + 1以上を入れると-1がreturnされるのはどうしてですか？

Tags: c, macos

**実行環境**
OS Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0
CPU intel i5-8500
コンパイラ gcc (中身はclangみたいです)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *buf = malloc(UINT_MAX);
    size_t i = INT_MAX;
    int n = write(1, buf, ++i);

    printf("%p\n%d\n%s\narg : %zu\nmax : %zd\n", buf, n, strerror(errno), i, SSIZE_MAX);
}
```

出力結果

```
0x101d22000
-1
Invalid argument
arg : 2147483648
max : 9223372036854775807
```

`man 2 write` で表示したマニュアルには以下の様に書いてありましたが、SSIZE_MAXはINT_MAXより大きいようでした

```
If the value of nbyte is greater than {SSIZE_MAX}, the result is implementation-defined.
```

どうして正常に出力されないのでしょうか？
同様のコードでもubuntuでは正常に出力されました
処理系定義なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> man 2 writeには以下の様に書いてありましたが

macOS 10.15 のマニュアルにはそのような記述は見つけられませんでした。

カーネルのソースコード(xnu の bsd/kern/sys_generic.c 内 `dofilewrite()`)を見ると、`INT_MAX` を超えると `EINVAL` となるコードがあります。ですので、macOS においてはこの挙動が期待される動作のようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。manはubuntuの方とごっちゃになっていました、すいません。システムコール関連で躓く度システムコールの実装を参照する方法が思いつかず、libcのsyscall系関数のソースを見て止まってしまっていました。いつも曖昧なまま放置していたのでとても勉強になりました。